# Filter DevExpress Grid Based on EF4 Partial Class Property Value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, filter, devexpress

Ok, so I'm a little new to DevExpress and I'm jumping into the middle of an existing project that makes heavy use of the DevExpress grid bound to a `LinqDataSource` and leverages the grids built-in filtering. Here's a quick overview of what I'm looking at:

- The grid is bound to a collection of EF4 entities called "Review".
- I have extended the Review entity via a partial class that contains a property called "IsCurrent". IsCurrent contains some logic that returns a boolean value.
- The initial datasource for the Grid contains ALL reviews that the current user could potentially see.
- We have leveraged DevExpress's built in ability to save grid layouts. Using the Filter Builder, we can filter on native properties of the Review entity (i.e. properties that exist in the generated entity model). So if "Name" is a member of the Review entity, filtering on `[Name]='Test'` works just fine.

What I REALLY want to do is filter also based on the property I created in the partial class "IsCurrent". However, when I modify the filter string that gets saved in our database and add `[IsCurrent]=true` to the filter string, I get a completely empty result set. I tried switching it to false and it is still empty.

Is is possible to filter on a property that is a member of the partial class and not the generated entity model? If not, is there an accepted workaround?

Here's some sample code that illustrates some of the important parts (albeit extremely simplified):

```
    protected void LinqServerModeDataSource1_OnSelecting(object sender, 
LinqServerModeDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
            {
        e.QueryableSource = GetAllRecords();
    }
```

**Review.cs partial:**

```
public partial class Review
{
    public bool IsCurrent
    {
       if (something)
           return true;
       else
           return false;
    }   
}
```

**DevExpress filter string:**

filter[IsCurrent] = true

If I change the filter to: filter[Name='Test'], it works just fine and shows me all of the records with a name of test. Reverting to [IsCurrent]=true just shows an empty set. I know for sure that result set contains valid data that should be displayed.

Any ideas? It seems like it's not working if I try to filter on values created in the partial class, but works for values obtained from the generated entity model.

Comment: ASPxGridView - This is an ASP.NET web forms application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [this community devexpress thread](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/71975.aspx) you will find the explanation for the limitation of using custom properties with LinqServerModeDataSource (see: Vest reply). Depends on your constraints to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to rebind the data or refresh the underlying data after changing the filter.

Comment: If that was the case, I don't think my other filtering would be working. I should clarify, filtering is working exactly as expected for the most part. This is the ONLY property I'm trying to filter on that is contained in a partial class and not the generated entity model and is the only property where filtering is not working.

Comment: What happens when you have your getter for IsCurrent just return true? Also, IsCurrent is just a getter, or does it have a setter also?

Comment: It only has a getter. IsCurrent is returning correct values. I added a bound column to the grid so I can see the values of IsCurrent for each row and they're all correct. It's just not filtering on it.